# SSRS report running successfully on one data source, when I run the same report connected to different data source the report is not loading

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report uses the stored proc-ABC. The ABC stored proc is in two different data sources 1 and 2. when I run the report connected to one data source-1 the report loads quickly, When I connect to different data source-2 the report says loading but never loads.

I have tried increasing the 'time out seconds' to Max and ran the report, I still see the same issue. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: what happens if you run the raw code for your data against the second data source?  Does it come back quickly with the results?

Comment: Hi Harry, you are right the problem is when I execute the storedprocedure  in that data source it is just executing but never loads, can I know how to fix this. the same stored proc runs in few seconds in other datasource.

Comment: This is a different issue all together then! Are you using SQL SERVER as your back end? If so.. compare the execution plans and see where the bottle neck is.. it could be a lack of index or similar. Ensure you have the same indexes setup.. if possible. Just an idea .. but too many variables as to what could be different